# How to check the last two digits?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SUBBIS
SUBB1D
SUBBD3
SUBB12
```

In above values, how can I check the last two digits (IS, 1D, D3, 12) are numbers using a sql code?

Answer (score 11):

Do you mean to fetch those values? You can do that with `like`:

```
where column like '%[0-9][0-9]'
```

If you need to ensure that the values always end with `2` numbers, you can do it with similar check constraint.

Comment: Look at this: http://rextester.com/WMPP59411 Maybe you have not explained your problem correctly.

Comment: @Amar Reddy: This answer is correct. If it doesn't work for you, then you've made a mistake somewhere. And what does "doesn't seem to work for somehow" mean anyway? Can you describe your problem with the query? Which string do you get you shouldn't get? Can you show the issue in rextester?

Comment: @AmarReddy - if you want *tested solutions*, maybe edit your question to include some *runnable code* that creates a sample table structure and sample data, and then give a clear explanation of the output you're looking for.

Comment: @James Z: I *love* these posts where people expect you to do all the work for them and then only give you monosyllabic answers when they don't like it or have not even understood your answer ... ;-)

Answer (score 6):

To check the last two digits are numbers in column, you can use the following script.

```
... WHERE ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(your_column,2)) = 1
```

Here `RIGHT(your_column,2)` will return the last two digits from the string.

or

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(your_column,2))
```

will return 1 (if its number) otherwise 0

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` answers the question nobody ever wants to ask. Unless you consider `1.` and `£1` to consist of just digits, I'd suggest this answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
SELECT MyId,
ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(MyColumn,2)) -- your column to check last 2 (if numeric)
FROM (
----- replace with your table
SELECT 1 MyId,'SUBBIS' MyColumn UNION SELECT 2,'SUBB1D' UNION 
SELECT 3,'SUBBD3' UNION  SELECT 4,'SUBB12' 
----- replace with your table
) A
```

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like` and `_` "underscore" to get last one digits record `columName`

```
SELECT columName FROM sub WHERE columName LIKE "SUBB__" ;
```

Record :

| columName |
| --- |
| SUBBIS |
| SUBB1D |
| SUBBD3 |
| SUBB12 |
| SUBBBA |